# Exchange 2010 SP1 upgrade to SP3 broke EWS connectivity

Tags: exchange-2010

Disclaimer: I know this is very obsolete technology: I am forced to use it by my client so please don't tell me to upgrade -- I don't have the choice.

So: we were running Windows Server 2008 R2 with Exchange Server 2010, and there was a C# application connecting as follows:

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
...
Service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
Service.Url = new Uri("http://EXAMPLE/ews/exchange.asmx");
Service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("EXAMPLENAME", "EXAMPLEPASS");
var results = Service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(20));
```

This worked fine on Exchange Server 2010 SP1. Now we have upgraded to SP3 and it suddenly fails with a 403 Forbidden error. I understand this might relate to tightening of security with the upgrade, but how can I connect in a way that SP3 will accept? What reconfiguration is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the SSL setting in IIS 7.

I had to go to IIS > Default Web Site > SSL Settings, and untick the "Require SSL" box. I suppose the upgrade from Exchange 2010 SP1 to SP3 must have ticked this box for some reason.

Comment: You can change the code to HTTPS and get a proper cert.
It would also be easier for your users to configure Outlook profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command to check configuration for EWS access:

```
Get-OrganizationConfig | Format-List EwsApplicationAccessPolicy,Ews*List
```

It shows the applications that are allowed access to EWS and REST.

If the value of EwsApplicationAccessPolicy is EnforceAllowList, only the applications specified in EwsAllowList are allowed to access EWS and REST. You could run below command to add C# application to access EWS:`Set-OrganizationConfig -EwsAllowList "c# APP"`

If the value of EwsApplicationAccessPolicy is EnforceBlockList, all applications are allowed to access EWS and REST, except those specified in EwsBlockList.

For more details: [Set-OrganizationConfig](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-organizationconfig?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: Thanks Joy. What is the syntax of the "C# APP" text? I added our filename ("Macrame.exe") but this did not change anything -- same 403 error occurs. For example is a full path required here?

Comment: It means Agent name, and these settings may take a few minutes (up to an hour) to propagate. Reference: https://practical365.com/exchange-server/managing-exchange-web-services-in-office-365/

Comment: Well, I changed EwsApplicationAccessPolicy to allow all applications, and still get the 403. I've noticed we also get the 403.4 error when visiting localhost in the browser on the Exchange server. It says SSL is required, but that is wrong (we have no SSL certificate). So I tried unchecking the "Require SSL" boxes in IIS 7 (for both Exchange and ExchWeb) but this had no apparent effect either.